# Wrapping a file in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, sugarcrm

I have some code to send data to SugarCRM in python, which seems to work. The problem comes when I try to send a file, as it all needs to be wrapped in a JSON object:

```
import sugarcrm

sugarcrm_user = "user"
sugarcrm_pass = "pass"
sugarcrm_url  = "http://url/rest.php"

sugarcrm_conn= None

try:
    sugarcrm_conn = sugarcrm.Sugarcrm(url = sugarcrm_url, username = sugarcrm_user, password = sugarcrm_pass)

    new_account = sugarcrm_conn.set_entry('Test_Images',{'uploadfile' : 'adsfsdf'})

except ValueError:
    print "can't connect to " + sugarcrm_url
    exit(1)
```

Is there a way of placing a file in a JSON object, so that I can send it to Sugar? Or are there any better ways of doing this?

I can add a file manually using SugarCRM in the browser, but sending a file is proving difficult. As far as I can tell, encoding the file before sending it, only stores it as an encoded string - no decoding is taking place.

[image] [image]

Comment: Assuming the file contains binary data, or characters not allowed within a JSON string, then you probably want to base64-encode the file content (https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) and send it as a JSON string

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I would have issues in Sugar? I am not sure if it decodes the files on the other end.

Comment: You can't send arbitrary binary data in JSON. So the general answer to your question "Is there a way of placing a file in a JSON object" is No. If you can give some more info on what data is in the file, what you're expecting Sugar to do with it, etc, then there might be another way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does that help? First image shows how a file can be added in SugarCRM and the second image shows the effects of encoding the file and sending it using python.

Comment: Are you using this: https://github.com/gddc/python_webservices_library ?

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that. However, it doesn't upload files does it? I can already upload text, it is only the file that is the problem.

Comment: It doesn't appear to support it and my (quick) look at the Sugar's API documentation didn't suggest they actually support it. Are you sure it's possible to do it at all?